# Have you been here?

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, geography

I am every man. I am named after a festival. I live in the largest of spaces. I belong to the thin. Uniquely, I began twice. What am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are...

> **Easter Island**

I am named after a festival

> Named after [Easter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter)

I live in the largest of spaces

> It's one of the most remote places on Earth and is located in the middle of the largest ocean

I belong to the thin

> [The narrow head statues that occupy the island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moai)

Uniquely, I began twice

> From [**The Culture of Easter Island**](https://islandculturearchivalsupport.wordpress.com/2018/03/16/the-culture-of-easter-island/): *"Oral traditions of the islanders state that **the island was settled twice**, the first time by a race known as the “Long-ears” who came from the east, and the second time by the “Short-ears” from the west. It seems the two clans were really the Hanau eepe (“short and stocky”) and theHanau momoko (**“tall and slim”**); the strange mix-up came from mistranslating eepe – short and stocky – as “ear” (“epe” in Rapa Nui). [...] For two centuries, the Short-ears willingly toiled to erect monuments that represented the long-eared chiefs of the original population."*

I am every man

> I feel like the statues represent that, but not sure about that one

Comment: Somehow feels like the first sentence should be the [complete opposite](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/no_man_is_an_island)...

Answer (score 0):

You are..

> **Burning Man**

I am every man.

> YES you are, Because traditionally culminates with the burning of a large wooden sculpture of a MAN.

I am named after a festival.

> Burning Man an Art festival, it slowly turn to culture?

I live in the largest of spaces.

> Burning Man is celebrated on an empty lake bed in Nevada's Black Rock Desert, For six days in late August. **Black Rock desert** is far from any cities or towns, and is very dry.

I belong to the thin.

> Not exactly, you gathered people very small area in a huge (more than 1000 sq.mi) **Black Rock desert**, might feel thin.

Uniquely, I began twice.

> Burning Man began as a **Bonfire ritual on the summer solstice** in 1986 when Larry Harvey, Jerry James, and a few friends met on Baker Beach in San Francisco and burned an 8 feet (2.4 m) tall wooden man as well as a smaller wooden dog.. No evidence it began twice..